# What map projection is this?

Tags: coordinate-system, video

I recently found a video on YT, but wondering what map projection the speaker is using while presenting the map at min. 10.54?

[image]

I would like to reproduce the results he is showing. Anyone having an idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Land border between US and Canada looks horizontal (flat E-W), while Montana - Wyoming are aligned vertically (N-S). It suggests a Mercator projection...just an observation, though.

Comment: Please include a screenshot rather than expecting potential answerers to follow a link and watch even part of a video.